# Undefined method `upvote_from' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Feels terrible asking this because it's probably very obvious but I am not able to spot the problem. I get the error

> NoMethodError in CommentsController#upvote
>   undefined method `upvote_from' for nil:NilClass

I have implemented acts as votable and its working for my startup, each startup has comments and I want to implement the same for the comments.

User.rb

```html
class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_votable
  acts_as_voter
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  has_many :startups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy
  has_one_attached :pic, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :confirmable
end
```

comment.rb

```html
class Comment < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_votable
  
  default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }

end
```

comments_controller.rb is the problem here in the controller and how do solve it?

```html
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_commentable
  before_action :upvote
  # before_action :downvote, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index ]
  # before_action :set_commentable, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  # before_action :set_comment, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy ]

  def index
    # @comment = Comment.all
  end

    def new
      # @comment = @commentable.comments.new
      @comment = Comment.new
    end

    def create
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
        @comment.user = current_user
        if @comment.save
            redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
          else
            render :new
          end
      end


      # Edit comments
      def edit
      end

      def update
        if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
          redirect_to @comment.commentable, notice: "Comment was updated."
        else
          render :edit
        end
      end


      def destroy
        @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
       @comment.destroy
     end
     
     def upvote
      @comment.upvote_from current_user
      redirect_to @comment.commentable, notice: "Comment was upvoted."
     end
     
     def downvote
      @comment.downvote_from current_user
      redirect_to @comment.commentable, notice: "Comment was downvoted."
     end

    private

    def comment_params
       params[:comment][:user_id] = current_user.id
       params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :commentable, :user_id)
     end

    def find_commentable
      @commentable = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment_id]) if params[:comment_id]
      @commentable = Startup.find_by_id(params[:startup_id]) if params[:startup_id]
    end

end
```

routes.rb

```html
 resources :comments do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
    member do
      put :upvote
      put :downvote
    end
  end
```

Kindly help spot the problem

Answer (score 0):

`@comment` is not set in `upvote` method, should be `@commentable`.

Also look into before_actions order - `upvote` requires `current_user`, so `authenticate_user!` should run before that